# How to use a class from the external biojava library

Tags: import, biojava

1. I am new to programming and would like to use a class from Biojava3.
       Specifically the getDNACodingSequences method from GeneIDXMLReader class.
       When I include the import statement below it does not compile.
       I also try to use the lookup function in eclipse and it does not see it as well.

   ```
   import org.biojava3.genome.parsers.geneid.GeneIDXMLReader

   Thanks in advance for the help.  I know this is basic stuff, but I am a rookie.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install BioJava first ...

http://www.biojava.org/wiki/BioJava:Download_3.0.6